# What is fastest searching algorithm for searching IPv6:port combination from given list of IPv6:ports in O(1) time compexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, networking

I want efficient searching algorithm for searching the IP:PORT combination form pre-stored list of IP:PORT in a given list of vector string.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

with the data structure of vector list, it's may very hard to have O(1) complexiy but O(n). because you must read the list at least once.  Bu if you do some pre process, and put them in map, you may get faster (almost O(1)) performance later in your program.